# Can oil price volatilily be used as an explanatory variable?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, garch, finance

I'd like to see if the oil price trend (as measured by WTI or Brent indexes) can help to predict the volatility of a stock.

I am using a GARCH approach to model volatility of the FTSE.

Now, if I want to know if the oil price volatility has an impact on FTSE's volatilty, can I use the returns on oil price as a variance regressor in my GARCH model?

Comment: You would use squared returns, right? Because raw returns could produce negative values (fitted or predicted) of conditional variance, which you do not want.

Comment: James, your first paragraph does not quite fit with the last two paragraphs. Could you clarify your question?

Comment: @RichardHardy As far as you first comment is concerned, I thought that the positive and negative shocks have the same impact on conditional volatility in a linear GARCH model. Doesn't this mean that there is no need to square the returns? Anyway, what I want to see is wheter the oil price can help to predict the conditional volatility of a stock. Actually I don't know if I should use oil price, its returns, or its [(un)conditional]  volatility. Could you help me?

Comment: There is a fundamental problem in having negative fitted/predicted volatility, and therefore you have to make the regressors in the cond. variance equation nonnegative. Squaring the returns is one way of doing so. Taking absolute values or making other transformations could be considered as well. In general, your question seems to be less about statistics and more about suject matter (finance). I am not sure if this is the right place to look for expertise in finance.

Comment: I would argue that there are more fundamental issues needing conditioning with such a laundry list of candidate predictors including spurious trends, stationarity, autocorrelation, cointegration, etc. Any response to the OPs question that is worth its salt should address them.

Comment: Guys, what do you think if I run Granger Causality test instead of this method? I've read some papers about it, but I don't understand why some authors run the test on stock prices and some run it instead on garch variance. What's the point of granger causality test on variance?

Comment: @James, it depends on what you are interested in. Look at the null hypothesis they are testing and you will see whether that is something you want to try as well. Statistical tests can be applied broadly, and it's your choice what to investigate.

Comment: @RichardHardy I'd like to tell you my idea and receive your critical comments.. would it be appropriate to explain it here or that would be OT?

Comment: I don't really do personal consulting, so it's better if you formulate your problem as a question that can be answered here. (Your problem might or might not be a good fit for Cross Validated.)